# How do I get the second token from a single string?

Tags: c

I'm looking for a way to use strtok to get the second token from a string.

```
    token = strtok(Input, "-");
    strcpy(first, token);
    token = strtok(NULL, "-");
    token = strtok(Input, ".");
    strcpy(name, token);
    token = strtok(NULL, ".");
```

The way the string is set up is : blah-blah.blah;blah.

every time I loop through, it just takes the first token. never picks up the second one.

Comment: @StoryTeller agh jesus. such an easy fix. thank you.

Comment: [sample code](http://ideone.com/O6e88E)

Comment: or `token = strtok(Input, "-.;");` at first time. then `token = strtok(NULL, "-.;");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strtok` is destructive. It modifies the input string is was passed initially into it. The modification consists of placing `\0` where formally the delimiter was. So your `Input` string gets "shortened" and appears to contain only the first token that was extracted. The simplest fix that prevents losing the place in your tokeniztion process is to replace

```
token = strtok(Input, ".");
```

with

```
token = strtok(NULL, ".");
```

Since you can always change the delimiter midway.